# Show Multi Line Custom Label in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, customlabel

I have a custom label "**This seat is already matched to another student. Please remove the existing match before matching this student.**" I want to display "**Please remove the existing match before matching this student.**" in another line line in LWC HTML.
HTML code:

```
<div class="slds-notify slds-notify_alert" role="alert">{label.match_success}</div>
```

Can we directly mention something in custom label so that it comes in new line or I have to manipulate in js file?

Comment: I have not tried, but can you adding html tag and in lwc use lighting formatted rich text tag.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding my comment as answer.

For this we can use [lightning-formatted-rich-text](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-rich-text/documentation) and add html tags in our custom labels.

For eg:

```
<lightning-formatted-rich-text value={label.labelWithHtml}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
```

Label:

```
<labels>
    <fullName>labelWithHtml</fullName>
    <categories>UI_Message</categories>
    <language>en_US</language>
    <protected>fa</protected>
    <shortDescription>labelWithHtml</shortDescription>
    <value>labelWithHtml <br> labelWithHtml</value>
</labels>
```

Comment: I get the error `Unexpected element {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}br during simple type deserialization` when including `<br>` tags in the label value

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Nagendra, I used lightning formatted rich text tag

```
<lightning-formatted-rich-text value={label.empty_table}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
```

and updated my label with "br" tag.